# Angular - passing a value with page size to another component - currentValue undefined Error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pagination

I'm building a table with pagination, using jw-angular-pagination

Here is my home.component.ts

```
 pageSize = 10;
```

home.component.html

```
<div (click)="pageSize=1 ">Change page size to 1</div>
...
<app-jw-pagination [items]="items" [size]="pageSize" (changePage)="onChangePage($event)"></app-jw-pagination>
```

I'm trying to pass a value to to Pagination.component.ts

```
    @Input() items: Array<any>;
    @Output() changePage = new EventEmitter<any>(true);
    @Input() initialPage = 1;
    @Input() maxPages = 3;
    @Input() size;

    constructor() {
    }

    pager: any = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        // set page if items array isn't empty
        if (this.items && this.items.length) {
            this.setPage(this.initialPage);
        }
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // reset page if items array has changed
        if (changes.items.currentValue !== changes.items.previousValue) {
            this.setPage(this.initialPage);
        }
    }

     setPage(page: number) {
        // get new pager object for specified page
        this.pager = paginate(this.items.length, page, this.size  , this.maxPages);

        // get new page of items from items array
        const pageOfItems = this.items.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);

        // call change page function in parent component
        this.changePage.emit(pageOfItems);
    }
}
```

It's working when I just pass a value that was set as a default in home component (10), but when I'm trying to change a value using function (click) I get an error

```
home.component.html ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentValue' of undefined
    at JwPaginationComponent.ngOnChanges (jw-pagination.component.ts:33)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.updateDirectives (home.component.html:421)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction
```

Is there maybe better way to do it to prevent that error, or maybe some way to fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

At the start Angular has a few cycle of change detection and it seems that in one of them the items @Input  array does not change.
What you want to do is access currentValue IF there is a change, 
so you should test that there is a change on the @Input items by :

```
if( changes.items ) {
      this.setPage(this.initialPage);
}
```

otherwise changes.items could be undefined if the array stay the same.

Also to better debug try console-logging changes to see the value of your data

Comment: I changed that a little bit, and my code looks like that


  if( changes.size || changes.items ) {
            this.setPage(this.initialPage);
        }


And it's working, but there is another error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at JwPaginationComponent.setPage (jw-pagination.component.ts:43)
    at JwPaginationComponent.ngOnChanges (jw-pagination.component.ts:37)

Comment: So basically I get this error when I start the application, after everything works well

Comment: I edited my response, console.log(changes) to clearly see the structure of your data.
you could also add the line 
debugger; to make your Browser stop in debug on your line and explore further. But in that case to see what your actual data a console.log should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethig like that:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.currentValue.items !== changes.previousValue.items) {
        this.setPage(this.initialPage);
    }
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange